# How do I display multiple geojson properties in a popup using Mapbox-GL?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to display two propeties from a geojson file in a popup on a map with points.

Here is an example of one item from the geojson file:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "LONG": 144.760809, "LAT": -37.866606, "STOP_ID": 19924, "STOP_NAME": "Aircraft  ", "2016_17_PATRONAGE": 294702, "2016_17_PATRONAGE_DAILY": 805.2, "METRO": "Yes" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 144.760809, -37.866606 ] } },
```

I am trying to display both the STOP_NAME and 2016_17_PATRONAGE_DAILY attributes in the same popup.

I have tried looking at [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/) and [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/) but neither approach seems to work.

This is my code so far (that works):

```
map.on('click', 'layername', function (e) {
    var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    var name = e.features[0].properties.STOP_NAME;

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML(name)
    .addTo(map);
});
```

I tried this code using the examples above:

```
map.on('click', 'layername', function (e) {
    var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    var name = e.features[0].properties.STOP_NAME;
    var patronage = e.features[0].properties.2016_17_PATRONAGE;

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML(name) + ' (' + properties.2016_17_PATRONAGE + ')')
    .addTo(map);
});
```

This didn't work and I got a message: "SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"

I'm fairly new to Mapbox-GL-JS so would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close. Just change that `setHTML` line to include an expression that references both properties:

```
.setHTML(e.features[0].properties.STOP_NAME + ' (' + e.feature[0].properties.2016_17_PATRONAGE + ')')
```

For convenience, I tend to do:

```
var p = e.features[0].properties;
```

So this would be:

```
.setHTML(p.STOP_NAME + ' (' + p.2016_17_PATRONAGE + ')')
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that! Turns out that the syntax error was caused by one of my columns in the CSV file beginning with a number.